# Writing string in CSV and getting multiple rows - Python

Tags: python, csv

This must be very simple.

I'm trying to put a header in my csv file, the string 'Date,Value', as you can see below.

with open('ticker.csv', 'wb') as f:

```
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerows('Date,Value')
writer.writerows(izip(dates, values))
f.close()
```

However I'm getting a multirowed string, like this:

D

a

t

e

","

V

a

l

u

e

2002-03,12.9

2002-04,12.5

2002-05,11.9

How can I fix that?

Comment: when using with open('ticker.csv', 'wb') as f:
you can avoid f.close() as it will inherently do it.
http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(['Date','Value'])
writer.writerows(izip(dates, values))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `writerow` - without the s - to write a single row.

Comment: thanks! almost there. now I'm getting D,a,t,e,",",V,a,l,u,e. How do I take out those commas between letters?